# Filter and display Data based on a single column (Datatables)

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using datatables to display the data. There are various columns that are part of the datatables, however i would like to show the row only if the value is set to "ABC" for a specific column.

Additionally there is also an export to Excel option provided which should be exporting all the data and not just the filtered data.

After looking at the api found there is .filter option, but it doesnt seem to work. (Can still see all the data)

Code snippet:

```
var table = $('.tableContent').DataTable({
        "autoWidth": false,
        "pageLength": 50,
        dom : 'lBfrtip',
        buttons : [ {
            extend : 'excel',
            text : 'Export to Excel'
        } ],
        "columnDefs" : [{
            "targets" : [ 0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 10, 11,  17, 18 ],
            "visible" : true,
            "searchable" : true
        }, {
            "targets" : [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 19, 20, 21 ],
            "visible" : false,
            "searchable" : false
        }]
    });

    var filteredData = table
        .column(17)
        .data()
        .filter(function(value, index) {
            return value.toLowerCase() == 'abc' ? true : false;
    });
```

Comment: Please show the code that you tried, for both filtering and export. This is insufficient for us to give any advice on.

Comment: @PeterB, the code has been updated now. Forgot to include the filtering part earlier.